# Not able to see "Create maven jobs" when adding on "new items" in jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

My aim to build a maven project in Jenkins .I have done the code implementation through Eclipse IDE.

I have downloaded Jenkins.war and placed it in web-apps directory of my Tomcat. Once I start my Tomcat and give the URL localhost:8080/Jenkins I get Jenkins dashboard. I have configured JDK_HOME and MAVEN_HOME by giving the path of my local .
But when trying to create MAVEN jobs on clicking "new items" in JENKINS,
  "create MAVEN jobs" option is not coming.
Can any one help me out here to resolve this ??
I am not sure is this a Maven plug-in issue or not ?
If not,then plz suggest me which Maven plug-in needs to be installed....
 Any help will be appreciated.
[Here image for Jenkins home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djXPv.png)

BR/Abinash

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins 2.0 doesn't go with `maven-plugin` by default.
You need to install it to be able to "Build a Maven project"
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin